# projection of product space is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_i,\mathcal A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of measurable spaces. Show that for $\emptyset\neq J\subset I$ the projection

$$p^I_J:\prod_{i\in I}\Omega_i\to\prod_{j\in J}\Omega_j, \otimes_{i\in I}\omega_i\mapsto\otimes_{j\in J}\omega_j$$

is measurable with respect to the corresponding product $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. $p_J^I$ is $\otimes_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i-\otimes_{j\in J}\mathcal A_j$ measurable.

I don't really know how to start with this. I know I have to show that for all $A'\in\otimes_{j\in J}\mathcal A_j$ I have to show that $(p_J^I)^{-1}(A')\in \otimes_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i$. But how can I show that?

Answer (score 2):

For any function $f\colon X \to Y$, and $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$, the family

$$f_\ast(\mathcal{A}) := \{ B \subset Y : f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}\}$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ (prove that).

Thus you need only show

$$(p_J^I)^{-1}(G) \in \otimes_{i\in I} \mathcal{A}_i$$

for $G$ belonging to a family generating $\otimes_{j\in J} \mathcal{A}_j$. The choice of the generating family should not be difficult.

Comment: I think I can generate $\otimes_{j\in J}\mathcal A_j$ by $\prod_{j\in J} \mathcal A_j^*$ with $\mathcal A_j^*:=\{B\subset \mathcal \Omega_j| (p_j)^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal A_j\}$, where $p_j: \prod_{i\in I}\Omega_i\to\Omega_j, \otimes_{i\in I}\omega_i \mapsto \omega_j$.
For $G\in\prod_{j\in J}\mathcal A_j^*$ we can write $G=\otimes_{j\in J} \tilde G_j$ with $\tilde G_j\in \mathcal A_j^*$.

Comment: I know that $(p_J^I)^{-1}$ basically maps this to something like $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\times ...\times \Omega_k \times (p_1)^{-1}(\tilde G_1)\times ...\times (p_n)^{-1}(\tilde G_n)$ which should be a part of the $\sigma$-algebra on $\prod_{i\in I}\Omega_i$, but how do I write this down correctly?

Comment: The product $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the $\prod_i E_i$, where $E_i \in \mathcal{A}_i$, and all but countably many $E_i$ are the entire space $\Omega_i$. The inverse image of such a set is a set of the same structure.